# Не точное определение адреса geolocation yandex maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Определяю автоматически адрес и координаты пользователя.
Координаты определяются достаточно точно, но в адресе не указывается улица.
Указывается только город.
Если вбить эти же координаты в сам сервис Яндекс карт, то он показывает улицу по координатам. Почему так?

```
 self.yamapsModel.data.geolocation
    .get({
      // Карта автоматически отцентрируется по положению пользователя.
      provider: "browser",
      mapStateAutoApply: true
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      // Получение местоположения пользователя.
      self.currPosition.adress = result.geoObjects
        .get(0)
        .properties.get("text");
      console.log(result.geoObjects.get(0));
      console.log("auto adress", self.currPosition.adress);
      self.currPosition.coordinates = result.geoObjects
        .get(0)
        .geometry.getCoordinates();
      console.log("auto coordinates", self.currPosition.coordinates);
      self.myMap.geoObjects.add(result.geoObjects);
      self.positionChange.emit(self.currPosition);
      // Определение адреса по координатам, проверка
      self.yamapsModel.data.geolocation
        .get(result.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates())
        .then(function(result2) {
          // Получение местоположения пользователя.
          console.log(
            "auto adress2",
            result2.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get("text")
          );введите сюда описание изображения
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: картинка 1]

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы получаете значение для сырых данных, полученных из результатов геолокации.
По умолчанию, обращение к геолокации также геокодирует данные местоположения, и к результатам можно обратиться вот таким образом:

```
ymaps.geolocation.get({
        // Зададим способ определения геолокации    
        // на основе ip пользователя.
        provider: 'browser',
        // Включим автоматическое геокодирование результата.
        autoReverseGeocode: true
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        // Выведем результат геокодирования.
        console.log(result.geoObjects.get(0)
            .properties.get('metaDataProperty'));
    });
```

Comment: Как вывести город из этих данных?

Comment: Ответ в этом случае следует обрабатывать как таковой же от http-геокодера. Он представляет собой стандартный json-объект. Город представлен как один из объектов массива GeocoderMetaData.Address.Components, заключённого в metaDataProperty.